# Extraño comportamiento de loop-for en Python

Tags: python-3.x, bucles

Tengo una lista anidada dada por

```
data = [[1, 1, "a"], [1, 0, "b"], [2, 5, "b"], [0.5, 0.4, "a"], [0, 0, "a"], [1, 1.2, "c"]]
```

Intento eliminar el carácter último de cada lista anidada en `data` previo copiado en otra lista llamada `coord_dataV` (para evitar perder los datos originales) y para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
data = [[1, 1, "a"], [1, 0, "b"], [2, 5, "b"], [0.5, 0.4, "a"], [0, 0, "a"], [1, 1.2, "c"]]
lines = 6
lrow = 3
dataV = data 
coord_dataV = dataV
for m2 in range(lines):
        coord_dataV[m2][lrow - 1] = 0
        print(coord_dataV)
        print(dataV)
        print(data)
        print("=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data")
        print()
```

Sé que podría eliminar dataV, pero haciéndolo así no entiendo porque las letras de `data` desaparecen así como las de `dataV`. ¿Puede alguien explicarme el porqué?

Resultado:

```
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 'b'], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 'b'], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 'b'], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data

[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 'b'], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data

[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 'a'], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data

[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 'a'], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data

[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 'c']]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data

[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 5, 0], [0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1.2, 0]]
=coord_dataV vs dataV vs data
```

Comment: La asignacion `lista2=lista` no hace una copia. Solo hace que lista2 se refiera a la misma lista que `lista`. Puedes crear una copia independiente con `lista2=lista.copy()`. Pero eso no copia a su vez las anidadas. Para ello necesitarias la funcion `deepcopy()` del modulo `copy`

Comment: @abulafia y se implementaría como ```dataV = deepcopy(data) 
coord_dataV = deepcopy(dataV)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás trabajando sobre las *mismas* listas (apuntan en memoria al sitio, es decir, misma referencia).
Con *coord_dataV = dataV* estás asignando la referencia de *dataV* a *coord_dataV*, es decir, apuntan a la misma lista (lo puedes comprobar si comparas el *id* de ambas listas, verás que es el mismo), lo mismo con *dataV = data*, ejemplo:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> c = a  # el id de c será el mismo que el id de a
>>> print(id(a), id(b), id(c))
>>> 140592021868424 140592014622664 140592021868424
```

Por ello, cualquier modificación a alguna de esas listas se verá reflejado en todas a la vez.
Para poder crear una lista distinta, será necesario que hagas una *deep copy*, ya que al trabajar con listas anidadas, si haces una *shallow copy*, seguirás usando referencias a las sublistas y las modificaciones se compartirán.

```py
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> a = [[1,2], [2,3]]
>>> b = deepcopy(a)
>>> c = a.copy() # equivalente a c = a[:] o c = list(a)
>>> b[0][0] = 4
>>> c[0][1] = 5
>>> print(a, b, c)
[[1, 5], [2, 3]] [[4, 2], [2, 3]] [[1, 5], [2, 3]]
```